# What are maximal ideals of $K[t]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $K[t]$ be the algebra of all polynomials in $t$. What are maximal ideals of $K[t]$? I know that $\langle t \rangle = \{tf \mid f \in K[t]\}$ is a maximal ideal. Are there other maximal ideals? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is $K$? A field?

Comment: There are infinitely many maximal ideals (Euclid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\,K\,$ is a field then $\,K[t]\,$ is an euclidean domain and as such also a PID (and even a UFD), so an ideal there is maximal iff it is prime iff it is generated by an irreducible polynomial of positive degree.

If $\,K\,$ is *not* a field things may be far away from being so pretty and simple...

Comment: Nonzero prime ideals maximal in UFD iff it's a PID, i.e. PIDs are precisely the UFDs of dimension $\le 1.\ \ $

Comment: Er....ok, I guess...(?)

Comment: What you wrote could be read as "... a UFD, so an ideal is maximal iff prime". But this is not a consequence of being a UFD. Rather it's a consequence of it being a PID. Perhaps you should reword it to avoid possible confusion on this point.

Comment: My main point, and that's why I wrote it in that order, is that the ring is an Euclidean domain, which brings all the rest. Hopefully now, with the added parentheses, there's no doubt.

Comment: Yes, the edit helps. Thanks.

Comment: Nop, thank you. Little things like this help to understand how other see things that one can easily oversee.

Answer (score 4):

If $K$ is algebraically closed then all the maximal ideals are of the form $\langle t - a\rangle$ where $a \in K$.  If $K$ is not algebraically closed there can be others, for example $\langle t^2 + 1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb R[t]$.